# Error while trying to save a point to Postgres DB using Postgis

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, postgis

My Entity class

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point location;
```

My spring boot configuration

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=****
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=**
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

I get the following error while trying to save.

ERROR: column "location" is of type point but expression is of type bytea   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.   Position: 154

Answer (score 1):

Seems like You're trying to store postgis [geometry(point) data type](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#PostGIS_Types) into field which data type is [postgresql point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html). They are not the same

Comment: Thanks so how do I represent the postgis point  type in my entity pojo using spring JPA.

Comment: Maybe try from the other way - change data type of column in database into geometry